# CouchDB Query View with Multiple Keys Formatting

Tags: view, key, couchdb

I'm having a problem getting a couchdb view to return the proper documents when using multiple keys.

**This works fine, returning the documents that match:**

GET http://example.com:5984/myDb/_design/myFilters/_view/getItemByForeignKeyId?key=abc123

**This returns returns all documents in the view, matching or not:**

GET http://example.com:5984/myDb/_design/myFilters/_view/getItemByForeignKeyId?keys=%5B%22abc123%22%5D

I'm usually very good at hunting down my answers. But, CouchDB documentation is very clear on the format for using multiple keys. I've seen some use the ?keys=[123,123] and i've also seen ?keys="abc","abc".

If anyone can offer any clarification on the 'proper' format and encoding of multiple key queries for CouchDB using a **GET** method, I would be extremely appreciative.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To get multiple keys from a view, you need to do a post request and submit the keys in the request body. Your HTTP request will look like this:

```
POST /myDb/_design/myFilters/_view/getItemByForeignKeyId
Content-Type: application/json

{
   "keys" : [
      "abc",
      "123"
   ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks you so much. That worked. The wording of the CouchDB documentation can be ambiguous at times.

Answer (score 9):

```
function(doc){
    {
        if([doc.key1, doc.key2])
            emit([doc.key1, doc.thingYouWantToKnow]);
    }
}
```

and in the query string, at the end

```
?key=["key1Value", "key2Value"]
```

Notice that it is `key=[]`, not `keys=[]` !!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 5):

Not saying it's correct, but you can actually do it via query string as well. The array enclosing brackets should not be encoded. E.g. this works for me:

`http://localhost:5984/test/_design/artists_albums/_view/albums_by_artist?keys=[%22Super%20bad%20artist%22,%20%22Fake%20artist%201%22]`

Comment: It's not documented. Is it ok to use it or should I opt for the POST request.