# Couch DB view key limit?

Tags: couchdb

I want to make a GET request to Couch to retrieve documents. using the following URL:

```
http://CouchServer/database_name/_design/design_name/_view/viewName?keys=["4302"%2C"4152"%2C"58"%2C"3248"%2Cetc..]
```

Can I pass in several thousand view keys?

Is there a better way of retrieving several thousand docs in CouchDB?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are upper limits on the length of a URL, which depends on both the client and server. Generally, it's not a problem, but I would recommend using a [`POST` request](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/1.6.1/api/ddoc/views.html?highlight=view#post--db-_design-ddoc-_view-view) instead, and putting those keys in the request body. (where you won't have the same limitations)

Comment: More on multiple couch view keys: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16763306/couchdb-query-view-with-multiple-keys-formating